# Linguagem C - Entendimento do Conceito de Ponteiros e Alocação Dinâmica, onde está o erro?

Tags: c

Gostaria de uma ajuda nos conceitos de chamada de ponteiro, e alocação dinâmica com `struct`.

Estou desenvolvendo um código para atender uma questão do trabalho de faculdade, e estou me deparando em alguns erros que acredito serem conceituais, porém, não estou conseguindo resolve-los. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Não sabia que havia restrição de auxílio numa comunidade de programação, tampouco devido a linguagem, então, talvez essa requisição de ajuda possa aparecer duplicada.

Meu problema está basicamente na função que eu crio o "relatório" das ações cadastradas, o compilador não retorna todas as informações cadastradas além de retornar uma mensagem de erro de .dll (sic!)

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100
#define QACOES 5

struct Data 
{
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
};

struct bvalores
{
    char codigoAcao[5];
    char areaAtuacao[MAX];
    struct Data data;
    float valorAbertura = 0;
    float valorFechamento = 0;
    double variAcao;
};

struct bvalores* acoes[QACOES];
int contador;

//recebe os dados digitados pelo usuário
void registros(struct bvalores* acoes)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    printf_s("Digite o código da ação: ");
    scanf_s("%s", &acoes->codigoAcao, 5);
    printf_s("Digite a área de atuação da empresa: ");
    scanf_s("%s", &acoes->areaAtuacao, MAX);
    printf_s("Qual o valor de aberta: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &acoes->valorAbertura);
    printf_s("Qual o valor de fechamento: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &acoes->valorFechamento);

    acoes->variAcao = (acoes->valorAbertura - acoes->valorFechamento) / acoes->valorAbertura;
    acoes->variAcao *= 100;

    printf("Data de lançamento: ");
    scanf_s("%d / %d / %d", &acoes->data.dia, &acoes->data.mes, &acoes->data.ano);
}

//registra cada ação com seus respectivos dados em uma posição da memória
void novoregistro()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    if (contador < QACOES)
    {
        *(acoes + contador) = (struct bvalores*)malloc(1 * sizeof(struct bvalores));
        registros(acoes[contador]);
        contador++;
    }
    else
    {
        printf_s("Só é possível 5 registros. Limite excedido");
    }
}

char menu()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    printf_s("\n");
    printf_s("Digite [I] para incluir um novo registro: \n");
    printf_s("Digite [R] para visualizar a variação das ações registradas: \n");
    printf_s("Digite [S] para sair do programa: \n");

    printf_s("\nQual a opção desejada: ");

    int opcao = getchar();
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        opcao = c;
    }
    return opcao;   
}

//função que monta um relatório dos registro das açoes
void relatorio()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    struct bvalores* acao;

    for (int i = 0; i <= contador; i++)
    {
        acao = *(acoes + i);
        printf_s("Ação da bolsa: %s  -  Area de atuação: %s\n", acao->codigoAcao, acao->areaAtuacao);
        printf_s("Data da operação: %d/%d/%d\n", acao->data.dia, acao->data.mes, acao->data.ano);
        printf_s("\n");
        printf_s("Valor de abertura: R$ %.2f  -  Valor de fechamento: R$ %.2f\n", acao->valorAbertura, acao->valorFechamento);
        printf_s("Variãção do dia: %.2f%%", acao->variAcao);
        printf_s("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    char sopcao;

    do 
    {
        sopcao = menu();
        switch (sopcao)
        {
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
            novoregistro();
            break;

        case 'R':
        case 'r':
            relatorio();
            break;

        default:
            printf_s("Opção invalida");
            break;
        }
    } while (sopcao != 'S' && sopcao != 's');   

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você não atribuiu um valor inicial à variável `contador` antes de utiliza-la.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SOpt. Nosso objetivo é formar um repositório de perguntas e respostas úteis a vários usuários de forma que se possa achar uma resposta através do mecanismo de busca, seja o embutido no site ou uma _search engine_ como o Google. Não há a restrição da linguagem como você falou e sim da pergunta ser sobre alguma dúvida referente a linguagens ou programação envolvendo as mesmas, ou conceitual. No caso da sua dúvida por exemplo é interessante reduzir o código ao mínimo necessário para reproduzir o problema e citar em forma de texto a mensagem ou log de erro que está sendo apresentada.

Comment: Também é interessante quebrar as suas outras dúvidas em perguntas individuais referentes a cada assunto. P.S.: Muito bom o seu codigo. Aproveite a oportunidade de usar a ferramenta e de fazer perguntas aqui.

Comment: Também tirar dúvidas sobre o funcionamento do site na área Meta (meta.pt.stackoverflow.com), que é um Q&A à parte. E lá também vale a busca.

Comment: Por último atente para a importância de adequar o título da pergunta à dúvida que está sendo perguntada, no seu caso como foram muitas ficou um texto muito genérico e menos útil para localizar.

Comment: Piovezan, agradeço as dicas...É minha primeira postagem e prometo seguir as suas orientações nas próximas...

Answer (score 2):

Fiz várias pequenas modificações para fazer seu código rodar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100
#define QACOES 5

struct Data 
{
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
};

struct bvalores
{
    char codigoAcao[6];
    char areaAtuacao[MAX];
    struct Data data;
    float valorAbertura = 0;
    float valorFechamento = 0;
    double variAcao;
};

struct bvalores acoes[QACOES];
int contador;

//recebe os dados digitados pelo usuário
void registros(struct bvalores* acoes)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    printf("Digite o código da ação: ");
    scanf("%s", acoes->codigoAcao);
    printf("Digite a área de atuação da empresa: ");
    scanf("%s", acoes->areaAtuacao);
    printf("Qual o valor de aberta: ");
    scanf("%f", &acoes->valorAbertura);
    printf("Qual o valor de fechamento: ");
    scanf("%f", &acoes->valorFechamento);

    acoes->variAcao = (acoes->valorFechamento - acoes->valorAbertura) / acoes->valorAbertura;
    acoes->variAcao *= 100;

    printf("Data de lançamento: ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &acoes->data.dia, &acoes->data.mes, &acoes->data.ano);
}

//registra cada ação com seus respectivos dados em uma posição da memória
void novoregistro()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    if (contador < QACOES)
    {
        //*(acoes + contador) = (struct bvalores*)malloc(1 * sizeof(struct bvalores));
        registros(&acoes[contador]);
        contador++;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Só é possível 5 registros. Limite excedido");
    }
}

char menu()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    printf("\n");
    printf("Digite [I] para incluir um novo registro: \n");
    printf("Digite [R] para visualizar a variação das ações registradas: \n");
    printf("Digite [S] para sair do programa: \n");

    printf("\nQual a opção desejada: ");

    int opcao = getchar();
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        opcao = c;
    }
    return opcao;   
}

//função que monta um relatório dos registro das açoes
void relatorio()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    struct bvalores* acao;

    for (int i = 0; i < contador; i++)
    {
        acao = &acoes[i];
        printf("Ação da bolsa: %s  -  Area de atuação: %s\n", acao->codigoAcao, acao->areaAtuacao);
        printf("Data da operação: %02d/%02d/%04d\n", acao->data.dia, acao->data.mes, acao->data.ano);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Valor de abertura: R$ %.2f  -  Valor de fechamento: R$ %.2f\n", acao->valorAbertura, acao->valorFechamento);
        printf("Variãção do dia: %.2f%%", acao->variAcao);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    char sopcao;

    do 
    {
        sopcao = menu();
        switch (sopcao)
        {
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
            novoregistro();
            break;

        case 'R':
        case 'r':
            relatorio();
            break;

        default:
            printf("Opção invalida");
            break;
        }
    } while (sopcao != 'S' && sopcao != 's');   

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

#### [Veja funcionando no ideone.com](https://ideone.com/CxTbfl)

Tentei mexer o mínimo possível no seu código, mesmo quando ele fere algumas boas práticas (veja explicações abaixo):

1. `char codigoAcao[6];`

   Você precisa sempre deixar um espaço extra para o terminador de *string*. e.g., a *string* `"PETR4"` é representada pelos caracteres `'P'`, `'E'`, `'T'`, `'R'`, `'4'`, `'\0'`.
2. `struct bvalores acoes[QACOES];`

   Você não precisa de um vetor de ponteiros para ações. Como o número de ações é fixo, um simples vetor de ações é suficiente.
3. `int contador = 0;`

   Enquanto não mexi na sua implementação, pois variáveis globais e estatísticas são inicializadas "zeradas", é boa prática sempre inicializar todas as variáveis (até para não esquecer de inicializar variáveis locais).
4. `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");`

   *Locales* são um assunto bem avançado e não quero entrar em detalhes. Dito isso `LC_ALL` é uma marreta poderosa (melhor evitada), e `Portuguese` não é portável. Além disso, acredito que setar o *locale* uma única vez seja suficiente para sua aplicação.
5. ```
    printf("Digite o código da ação: ");
    scanf("%s", acoes->codigoAcao);
    printf("Digite a área de atuação da empresa: ");
    scanf("%s", acoes->areaAtuacao);
   ```

   Em C vetores decaem em ponteiros, ou seja, algo como `char codigoAcao[6]` é visto como um `char*` apontando para o primeiro elemento do vetor. Dessa maneira, ao ler uma *string* não é necessário usar `&`.
6. ```
     acoes->variAcao = (acoes->valorFechamento - acoes->valorAbertura) / acoes->valorAbertura;
   ```

   Tinha um errinho na conta que produzia variações negativas para ações em alta. Tive que inverter abertura e fechamento.
7. ```
    //*(acoes + contador) = (struct bvalores*)malloc(1 * sizeof(struct bvalores));
    registros(&acoes[contador]);
   ```

   Devido a mudança no item 2 não é mais necessário alocar memória dinamicamente. Em compensação se torna necessário passar o endereço da ação para a função `registros`.
8. ```
    for (int i = 0; i < contador; i++)
    {
        acao = &acoes[i];
        printf("Ação da bolsa: %s  -  Area de atuação: %s\n", acao->codigoAcao, acao->areaAtuacao);
        printf("Data da operação: %02d/%02d/%04d\n", acao->data.dia, acao->data.mes, acao->data.ano);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Valor de abertura: R$ %.2f  -  Valor de fechamento: R$ %.2f\n", acao->valorAbertura, acao->valorFechamento);
        printf("Variãção do dia: %.2f%%", acao->variAcao);
        printf("\n");
    }
   ```

   Aqui ocorreram várias pequenas modificações.

   - Troquei `<=` por `<` para evitar acessar ações não inicializadas ou fora dos limites do vetor.
   - A lógica para acessar cada ação também foi modificada conforme itens 2 e 7.
   - Várias pequenas mudanças nas *strings* de formatação.

**OBS**: Não usei `printf_s` e `scanf_s` pois eles não estão disponíveis na *glibc* (na verdade, nunca vi essas funções sendo usadas fora do mundo Microsoft). Pesquisando sobre o assunto, me parece que há certa controvérsia em relação a TR 24731-1, dito isso, se portabilidade não for prioridade fica a seu critério usar as versões *safe*.

`system("pause");` também só funciona no Windows e não faz muito sentido para um programa que já pausa para ler do teclado em outros pontos.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas orientações, não sou da área de programação, mas meu curso possui algumas matérias e realmente, não prestei atenção em alguns conceitos.

A questão da alocação dinâmica é um item solicitado no trabalho como obrigatório.

Mesmo assim vou ler e estudar cada um dos seus comentários e retorno aqui com um feedback.

Novamente, muito obrigado pelas orientações.